# Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError In java

Tags: java, exception

I have problems with these methods.

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: pkgModelo.AnalizadorLexico: method <init>()V not found
```

The classes are:

Class frmAnalizador:

```
package pkgVista;
import pkgModelo.AnalizadorLexico;

public class frmAnalizador extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    AnalizadorLexico alexico;
    String linea;
    JFileChooser abrirArchivo;

    public frmAnalizador() {
        initComponents();
        alexico = new pkgModelo.AnalizadorLexico();
    }
}
```

In object `alexico` show the exception.

Class AnalizadorLexico:

```
package pkgModelo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class AnalizadorLexico implements AnalizadorLexicoConstants {

    public AnalizadorLexico() {
    }

    public static void principal(FileInputStream file) throws ParseException {
        try {
            AnalizadorLexico analizador = new AnalizadorLexico(file);
            analizador.Algoritmo();
            System.out.println("El analizador l\u00e9xico ha compilado correctamente");
        }
        catch(ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Hay errores: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in this line AnalizadorLexico analizador = new AnalizadorLexico(file); you passed file object as a parameter where as your class  AnalizadorLexico has not any kind of parameterized constructor so you have to make one more constructor which has a parameter of FileInputStream.

```
public AnalizadorLexico(FileInputStream file){

     //Your Code
}
```